# Holy Alphabet Arithmetic

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, no-computers

$Given$:

$A$+$B$+$C$=3

$B$+$C$+$D$=3

$C$+$D$+$E$=1

$D$+$E$+$F$=1

What is

$E$+$F$+$G$=?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> $0$

Reasoning

> The number on the right represents the total number of closed regions in the letters on the left.
>  In particular $A$ has $1$, $B$ has $2$ and $D$ had $1$ but $C, E, F$ and $G$ have none.

Comment: Got it..........